# Is it possible to fetch nearest events in meetup.com GRAPHQL API?

Tags: graphql, meetup

I'm currently in search of a query to retrieve nearby events using latitude and longitude parameters within the GraphQl meetup.com API. Despite dedicating some time exploring the documentation, I haven't come across a query that aligns with my specific needs.

Currently, my code is designed to query events based on a specific search string. However, I'm looking to enhance it to query all events without a specific search string.

```json
query {
  keywordSearch(filter: {
    query: "HashiCorp Solutions and Testing with Terraform",
    lat: 57.10557,
    lon: 12.25078,
    radius: 100,
    source: EVENTS
  }) {
    count
    edges {
      cursor
      node {
        id
        result {
          ... on Event {
            title
            eventUrl
            description
            dateTime
            going
            shortDescription
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate your help in finding the right query or receiving any guidance you may have.

Comment: If you look at Meetup's docs it seems that `query` is always required so you can't do an all inclusive search. OTOH if you inspect a meetup.com page they use a saved query (from their private gql api) that allows for a search without a query string (by location only)